# Using PDF files as images

Tags: image, cocoa, pdf

In the past i have used PDF images of vector files in an NSImage, the advantage being that i can scale them without losing quality. I know that people usually use jpg and png files, why is this? Do PDF files significantly reduce performance or is there some other reason?

Thank you in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what's in your PDF file. If there's enough going on in it, then yeah, a raster image may be faster. The trade-off is, of course, scalability—you end up needing to create 1x and 2x variants for every destination size, or create an icon family (if appropriate), instead of just using one image for everything.

But I think most people create raster resources because that's the sort of tool they're used to: Photoshop, Pixelmator, or Acorn. Not many people use vector editors or write their art in PostScript. (And the field of vector editors available on the Mac is pretty weak.)

My recommendation for a few years now has been an app called [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/). It's vector-focused, but can export raster images in multiple sizes, PDFs, and even source code.

Comment: An app called [Intaglio](http://www.purgatorydesign.com/Intaglio/) also does vector images with export to PDF.  No idea how it compares to Opacity.

Answer (score 0):

I use PDF files too, for precisely the same reason that they scale automatically.  Apple do the same (look inside the Xcode.app bundle - you won't find much other than `.pdf` files).

There is no reason to use `.jpg` or `.png` files at all.

Comment: Ok, i'll continue using them then. Thanks :)